# How to str_slug into model?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

search.blade.php

```
@foreach($search as $item)
<div class="post">
    <a href="{{url($item["ID"].'/'.$item["row_name"]).'.html'}}">
</div>
@endforeach
```

SearchController.php

```
public function postSearch(SearchRequest $request){

        $search_key = $request->input('search');
        $key_space  = str_slug($search_key," ");
        $search     = moives::where('row_name','like',"%$key_space%")
                    ->orderBy('id','DESC')
                    ->get();
        if(count($search) > 0){
            return view('user.pages.search',compact('search','search_key'));        
        } 
        else {
            return view ('user.pages.search')->withMessage('No Details found. Try to search again !');
        }
    }
```

Url results:

http://lar.dev/blog/11609/Beauty%20and%20the%20Beast.html

But I want results:

http://lar.dev/blog/11609/Beauty-and-the-Beast.html

The condition here is that I can not add columns to the database, I can only retrieve data from the database.

Answer (score 0):

In order to divide words with `-` use `str_slug` like this:

```
str_slug($string,"-");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="{{url(str_slug($item["ID"].'/'.$item["row_name"],'-')).'.html'}}">
```